# Add an image for custom keyboard (swift)

Tags: xcode, swift, image

Is there any way to add an image like adding text? I'm using:

```
    var proxy = textDocumentProxy as! UITextInput
    proxy.insertText("hello world")
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that this is **NOT possible**. Both [UITextInput](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInput_Protocol/) and [UIKeyInput](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKeyInput_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIKeyInput) do not provide such a functionality.